# Using $locationChangeStart for preventing the location change not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have form which when edited and if the user redirecting to new page, i has to give a warning message for not saving the data. Once the user press ok, it has to redirect to the expected page. I able to bring the message by preventing the lcoation change, but once clicking the ok button, the path is not changing.

```
 $scope.$on "$locationChangeStart", (event, newUrl) ->
    if userSettingsService.getUserDataFormEdited()
      event.preventDefault()
      alertService.show($scope.formNotSaved)
      .then (response) ->
          switch
            when response.isOK()
              $window.location.href = newUrl
              return
          return
```

The alertService is responsible for the warning message

Is this approach of using $locationChangeStart is correct? Please help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that angular **do** the change of route in the browser anyway at first.

So even if you add code the check/validate anything, you have to handle the browser path revert manually :

```
$window.history.back();
```

But I don't think that is what you want to do, the best solution is to handle your `alert` before any change of route. I suggest you to add your code in the `ng-submit` property of your `form` instead.